# Ubuntu Server 16.04 - Errors were encountered while processing fail2ban

Tags: server, apt, dpkg, fail2ban

When I try to install fail2ban on my Ubuntu Server 16.04

```
apt-get -install fail2ban
```

I am getting error message: "Errors were encountered while processing fail2ban"
I've tried unninstall fail2ban with theses commands but I still recieve this error message when I try install this package.

```
apt-get purge fail2ban
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

**/etc/fail2ban/jail.local**

```
[pureftp]
enabled = true
port = ftp
filter = pureftp
logpath = /var/log/syslog
maxretry = 3

[dovecot-pop3imap]
enabled = true
filter = dovecot-pop3imap
action = iptables-multiport[]name=dovecot-pop3imap, port="pop3,pop3s,imap,imaps", protocol=tcp
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 5

[postfix-sasl]
enabled = true
port = smtp
filter = postfix-sasl
logpath = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 3
```

If you need more information just ask.
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: Have you done `sudo reboot` and tried again? (I know, Linux system shouldn't need reboots, but it can't hurt)

Comment: same error message after reboot

Comment: probelm solved after i removed directory fail2ban `rm -rf /etc/fail2ban`